# How to return User's profile picture that is stored in my filestyem (is /tmp folder save to put it there for temporary extraction)

Tags: php, yii

I'm saving new registered user's profile picture in my Yii application's protected/data folder under a folder with his user-id.

The client (a mobile app) whenever logging in will retrieve some basic info ... among which is his profile picture.

Should I point them straight to the jpg inside protecte/data/user/pic.jpg OR should I temporarily push that picture in /tmp folder and point them to the temporary file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it straight to the file, nothing's wrong with that. If you did it in a tmp file, it would be OK, but it could accidentally delete itself.

Comment: Doesn't pointing a client to a file system within the actual development have any security risks with it? Anyway what I've done is .. made a tmp folder under /var/www .. save the file I need to send by naming it with Date('U') (to avoid naming conflicts) .. and I delete it once I get confirmation from the client that they've gotten the file...

Comment: Not really, think about this - websites for example, they are not in tmp directories... they are in normal directories, nothing goes wrong. I'd recommend normal directories. TMP directories could be deleted on accident by your server.

Comment: Ok, I guess I got my answer. Thanks @LeSamAdmin

Comment: No problem, if you need anymore help... let me know! :)